# How to get the particular value of key by giving the key name?

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [domain] => alphaanalysis.org
        [status] => available
    )
}
```

I have the array and it's elements like this. I just need the value of domain key. How to get that, I don't know. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your array is $x you can use:

```
$x[0]->domain
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
     $array[0]->domain; 
 ?>
```

If your array is $array then you can try this.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this syntax for that

```
$arraynem[]->key;
```